# Prolog not halting when implementing reverse list

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

This is my implementation:

```
popped_last_el([], [_]).
popped_last_el([F | R], [F | X]) :- popped_last_el(R, X).

last_el(X, [X]).
last_el(X, [_ | L]) :- last_el(X, L).

reverse_list([], []).
reverse_list([F | R], L2) :- last_el(F, L2), popped_last_el(L, L2), reverse_list(R, L).
```

When I query `reverse_list([a, b], X)`, it outputs `X = [b, a]` as expected. But when I ask for another solution using `;`, prolog runs indefinitely. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

Here is a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) to explain why the program still loops. Only this very tiny part of your program is *responsible* for non-termination. You will have to fix *something* in that part to make non-termination go away.

```
last_el(X, [X]) :- false.
last_el(X, [_ | L]) :- last_el(X, L), false.

reverse_list([], []) :- false.
reverse_list([F | R], L2) :-
   last_el(F, L2), false,
   popped_last_el(L, L2),
   reverse_list(R, L).

?- reverse_list([a, b], X), false.
   loops.
```

What you can see from this failure-slice:

`L2` needs to be known ('instantiated') to make `last_el/2` terminate. But it is not.

Comment: How did you know where to slice/put the falses or is it just trial and error until the script doesn't terminate?
Also I can't find a way to fix the problem. Is this approach a lost cause?

Comment: The following always holds: **if** a fragment does not terminate, then the entire program does not terminate. Some of that can be determined quite easily. And some need to be tried out. (I, in this case, just tried this one first.) See [tag:failure-slice] for more.

Comment: *Is this approach a lost cause?* there are better ways. You can (with low effort) write a pure version that terminates for both `reverse_list([a,b],Xs)` **and** `reverse_list(Ys,[a,b])`. You should really try this yourself (but you find it also here on SO...).